# Are multi-region KMS keys required for encrypting a multi-region CloudTrail trail?

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-kms, amazon-cloudtrail

I have a multi-region trail defined with Terraform that I'm trying to encrypt with KMS. My trail covers four AWS regions: `us-east-1`, `us-west-2`, `eu-west-2`, and `eu-central-1` and I'm creating a KMS key for encrypting the log files and adding the appropriate permissions per the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/encrypting-cloudtrail-log-files-with-aws-kms.html). However, it's not clear whether or not this needs to be a multi-region key. If the KMS key I use needs to be multi-region, do I need to make a replica key for each additional region that my trail covers?

The docs say CloudTrail supports KMS multi-region keys, but the appropriate situation(s) to use MRKs w/ CloudTrail isn't straightforward. If I could get that far, then I do know that related MRKs do not share key policies and that I would need to define a specific policy for each should I need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not mandatory to use multi region keys with CloudTrail. When you configure a trail and want to encrypt the CloudTrail log files, you can use a single KMS key to encrypt the files. Just make sure the KMS key is in the same region as the S3 bucket where you're sending the log files to.

Comment: Thank you. I missed this in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/encrypting-cloudtrail-log-files-with-aws-kms.html) before. "You can use a single KMS key to encrypt and decrypt log files for multiple accounts across all regions."